# Next Error: Export encountered errors on following paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I try to `npm run build`. Why Build error?

> Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /blogs/pos1
> /blogs/post2
> /blogs/post3

[image: Export encountered errors on following paths]

My code:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const post = context.params.post;
    const res = await axios({
         method: 'get',
         url: `...=${post}`});
    return {
      props: {
        post: post,
      },
      revalidate: 1,
    }
  }

  export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const posts = await lastPost();
  
    return {
      paths: posts.data.data.map((post) => {
        return {
          params: {
            post: post.seourl,
          },
        }
      }),
      fallback: true,
    }
  }
```

---

I noticed that it  manifest.json instead of ${puts} and I used the post method and axios was able to get the answer but there is still the problem of not creating pages.

Comment: Sorry but, url: `...=${post}`}); what is this?

Comment: I deleted the api address here .

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous question you deleted, those pages are probably failing to build because the axios requests are getting a non-200 response. You need to catch and handle the errors.